# Add %20 as part of date format in shell

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix, date-formatting

I am trying to add %20 between the date and time, to return `YYY-MM-DD%20HH-MM-SS`

How can I escape the % symbol?

```
date '+%Y-%m-%d%20%H:%M:%S'
```

Returns:

```
2023-02-06                   %H:12:40
```

And when I quote the %20:

```
date '+%Y-%m-%d\"%20\"%H:%M:%S'
```

The quotes are also returned:

```
2023-02-06"%20"11:13:59
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conversion specifier `%%` expands to a literal `%`

```
$ date +%%
%
```

so

```
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S'
2023-02-06%2011:20:17
```

However, as this implies you are using the string in a URL, I would recommend simply outputting a space, and letting whatever is constructing the URL ensure that necessary characters are escaped.

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the `%` with another `%`, i.e. by doubling it:

```
$ date '+%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S'
2023-02-06%2017:19:38
```

As noted in [`date(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html):

> ```
> FORMAT controls the output.  Interpreted sequences are:
>
> %%     a literal %
> ```